# Why am I getting an Assertion Error on this Python code?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, assert

I have a function written here:

```
def addItem(aBookcase, name, mediaType):
    """
    Returns False if aBookcase is full, otherwise returns True and 
    adds item of given name and mediaType to aBookcase.
    """
    pass
    emptySpacesBefore = aBookcase.getEmptySpaces()
    if aBookcase.getEmptySpaces() == 0:
        added = False
        return added
    else:
        position = findSpace(aBookcase)
        aBookcase.setName(*position, name=name)
        aBookcase.setType(*position, mediaType=mediaType)
        added = True
        emptySpacesAfter = aBookcase.getEmptySpaces()
    assert added is True, "No free positions"
    assert emptySpacesAfter < emptySpacesBefore, "Same amount of empty spaces"
    assert aBookcase.getName(*position) is name, "Error with name"
    assert aBookcase.getType(*position) is mediaType, "Error with media type"
```

Yet when I go to test the function with this line of code:

```
assert addItem(small, "Algorhythms, date structures and compatibility", BOOK)
```

I get an 'AssertionError' as shown here:

[image: Screenshot of 'AssertionError']

So if I'm right, it means I'm not handling it but I'm not sure how or why? Is it something wrong with my code? Something missing? etc.

Comment: Can you put the text of the assertion error in the question? Some people (such as myself) are on a network that blocks imgur.

Comment: @AndrewLamarra: help for the blind: top left corner (just noticed it right now): `ity", BOOK)`, then "assertion unhandled by this code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when it works properly, your `addItem` function returns nothing, so it returns `None`, which is seen as a failure by the last `assert` statement that you inserted. You should return `added` for both cases (`True` or `False`)

BTW since you reached that line, it means that all previous assertions are OK so good news: your code is OK.

Comment: Thank you ever so much. As simple as forgetting the 'return added' statement haha. Might wear that dunce hat in the corner right about now :D.

Comment: I just noticed the need for `return`. Post edited. Make sure to stay at least 10 minutes in that corner :)

Comment: I feel even more silly now, I did actually have the 'return added' statement in the else clause in the first place but accidentally removed it when I put in the first 'assert' line ha. Don't know why/how I did, think I must have highlighted. Thanks again

Comment: 10 minutes? Phew, less than what I was planning :L.